# Node - request authentication using secret

Tags: rest, authentication

Lets assume i have REST api with products and i want it to be accessible only for specified users.

The list of users is known for me and i'm looking for some way to give them safe access to my API.

I don't want to create authentication with username and password, generate token and this stuff.

What i can imagine is that i'm giving each of my users some secret string
and they use it in every request.

And what i need is some example/tutorial/name of this kind of solution, 

i'm sure there are some standards for that but i don't know it.

I know it's kind of nooby question - sorry for that, i'm just asking ;).

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a simple shared-secret authentication. A simple solution in this case is just to check for the secret as a param (or it could be in the request header). For example, the client can call:

```
https://example.com/valuable-stuff?secret=2Hard2Gue$$
```

You implement this in your web request handler as:

```
SECRET = '2Hard2Gue$$'
function showValuableStuff() {
   if (params['secret'] != SECRET)
     return NotFounderError;
   // now retrieve and output the resource 
}
```

Some practical considerations are:

- Use a secure connection for this to prevent the secret being leaked (ie a secure HTTPS exposure).
- Be careful where you store the source code if you're hard-coding it. A fancier solution is use an environment variable which is set on the server, so you keep this out of the source code. Or at least to encrypt the part of the source that contains the secret.

While this is fine for simple solutions, it violates the basic security principle of accountability because you are sharing the secret with multiple people. You might want to consider allocating each individual their own random string, in which case, you may as well use [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) as it's well supported by Apache and other web servers, and still quite a lightweight approach.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful answer